# Geographic Routing Questions (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS question about geographical routing and DNS redirection.

Please let me know what function you should use to do this:

1. **Current Configuration:** USA user -> `main.com` Domain Access -> CloudFront -> EC2 in Seoul Region

- When a U.S. user calls `mail.com`, the final server after redirection to `main.com` is EC2 in Seoul Region.
- When a Japanese user calls `mail.com`, the final server after redirection to `main.com` is the EC2 of Seoul Region.
- The original domain should only be marked as `main.com` in Korea.

Users will have to call each domain, redirect it to each country's domain, and then go to EC2 in the Seoul Region via CloudFront.

I'm asking you a question because I can't find an answer even if I look it up.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is unclear. Are you saying that you want this current behaviour (always going to Seoul), or do you want it to do something different? What do you mean by "Users will have to call each domain"?